# Bug In a Function that Removes Duplicates In a Singly Linked List

Tags: c++

I am writing a function that removes duplicates in a linked list for my C++ program. I do get an error every time I test the function and I could not determine why. The program should return true if there are nodes with duplicated values and removed successfully in a sorted singly linked list, else returns false. Here is the function:

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next = NULL;
};
bool RemoveDuplicatesSorted(struct node* head){
    struct *node = head;
    while (node != nullptr && node->next != nullptr){
        if (node->data == node->next->data){
            duplTemp* temp = node->next;
            node->next = node->next->next;
            delete temp;
            return true;
        }else{ 
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

These are the errors I get:

```
    main.cpp:10:20: error: cannot convert ‘node*’ to ‘int*’ in initialization
   10 |     struct *node = head;
      |                    ^~~~
      |                    |
      |                    node*
main.cpp:11:37: error: request for member ‘next’ in ‘* node’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   11 |     while (node != nullptr && node->next != nullptr){
      |                                     ^~~~
main.cpp:12:19: error: request for member ‘data’ in ‘* node’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   12 |         if (node->data == node->next->data){
      |                   ^~~~
main.cpp:12:33: error: request for member ‘next’ in ‘* node’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   12 |         if (node->data == node->next->data){
      |                                 ^~~~
main.cpp:13:13: error: ‘duplTemp’ was not declared in this scope
   13 |             duplTemp* temp = node->next;
      |             ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:13:23: error: ‘temp’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘mktemp’?
   13 |             duplTemp* temp = node->next;
      |                       ^~~~
      |                       mktemp
main.cpp:13:36: error: request for member ‘next’ in ‘* node’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   13 |             duplTemp* temp = node->next;
      |                                    ^~~~
main.cpp:14:19: error: request for member ‘next’ in ‘* node’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   14 |             node->next = node->next->next;
      |                   ^~~~
main.cpp:14:32: error: request for member ‘next’ in ‘* node’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   14 |             node->next = node->next->next;
      |                                ^~~~
main.cpp:15:20: error: type ‘’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
   15 |             delete temp;
```

To the best of my knowledge, I believe that I have written the function successfully even after checking multiple websites that follow the same algorithm. However, I could not determine the mistake that sckrewed the whole code up.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `struct *node = head;` is illegal. If you want to define a pointer to `struct node`, you should have

```cpp
struct node *p = head;
```

Secondly, unless you have defined a type `duplTemp`,

```cpp
duplTemp* temp = node->next;
```

doesn't make any sense. I guess you want to have

```cpp
struct node *temp = node->next;
```

Finally, I would recommend you to use different names for a class and a variable. For example, use `Node` for the class and `node` for the variable.

Then the above statement could be rewritten as

```cpp
Node *temp = node->next;
```

You used `node` to name both a class and a variable. While this is possible, it could be confusing, and troublesome. You would need to explicitly write `struct` before the class `node` whenever there is ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you! Are my return and false statements correct?

Comment: I wanted to be specific to the errors you posted. Frankly, there seems to be more problems in your program, but making mistakes and trying best to identify them ourselves is part of learning. For example, in the `while` loop I don't see any incremental change if the data in `head` and its `next` are different. In this way you only checked the `head`, but not the following nodes.